# How can I put special characters in an enum value in apollo graphQL server?

Tags: node.js, enums, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have a problem with the enum type in apollo-graphQL, I'm using apollo-server in nodejs.
The problem is that I can't use strings with a value like image/jpeg or svg+xml.
It's giving me errors that these values can't be parsed as enums.

[image: Enum values]

[image]

Can somebody tell me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the answer is that you cannot. According to the GraphQL spec, an [enum is defined](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Enum-Value) as

> *Name* but not **true** or **false** or **null**

"Name" here refers to [this definition](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Names), which defines a "Name" with the regular expression

```regex
/[_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*/
```

This means that enums (which are defined as "names values") can only have letters, numbers, or underscores, and the first character can't be a number. Additionally, the spec recommends that you use "all caps", which I read to mean "CONSTANT_CASE".

If an enum really is what you want, to follow the recommendation of the spec, you "should" use

```
enum ImageMimeTypes {
  IMAGE_APNG
  IMAGE_AVIF
  IMAGE_GIF
  IMAGE_JPEG
  IMAGE_PNG
  IMAGE_SVG_XML
  IMAGE_WEBP
}
```

though I personally like to name my enums as singular constant case, as well -- just so it's less a surprise of what it represents -- so I'd probably call it `IMAGE_MIME_TYPE`.

Comment: Thank you for laying out the breadcrumbs. Reading the enum specs isn't immediately clear, until you read the spec for a "name". We ran into this issue with the Ruby library for GraphQL - it's currently *not* enforcing the spec, so our javascript layer failed when it received an enum that started with a number.